# Null Pointer Exception in Bitmap.decodeResources() from xml resource

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap

In my current android project I create two bitmaps from xml resources. Every time I build my project using the xml bitmaps as the resource for `Bitmap.decodeResources()` I get a null pointer exception when I try to access the bitmaps. But when I switch to using the straight .png the error goes away.

Why is `decodeResources()` returning null?

code where the bitmaps are created:

```
public OvertButton(float x, float y, float width, float height, int pressedId, int  unPressedId, Resources res, boolean visible) {
    \\these are null if xml bitmap is passed
    pressed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, pressedId); 
    unPressed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, unPressedId);

    this.visible = visible;
    relocate(x, y);
    resize(width, height); //throws NPE when I createScaledBitmap()

    ClickableManager.registerClickable(this);
}
```

resource file

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/play_button_pressed"
    android:filter="false"
    android:antialias="false"
    android:dither="false"/>
```

and the resize method

```
@Override
    public void resize(float width, float height) {
        box.set(box.left, box.top, box.left + width, box.top + height);
        Log.d("resize",String.valueOf(height));
        pressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pressed, (int)width, (int)height, true);
        unPressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unPressed, (int)width, (int)height, true);
    }
```

And the logcat

```
04-16 09:45:06.341  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-16 09:45:06.450  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/MenuActivity﹕ 2130837594$$$2130837596
04-16 09:45:06.451  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
04-16 09:45:06.451  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/OvertButton﹕ true2130837591
04-16 09:45:06.457  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/OvertButton﹕ false2130837595
04-16 09:45:06.457  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/resize﹕ 252.0
04-16 09:45:06.458  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-16 09:45:06.459  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41610d40)
04-16 09:45:06.461  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.handmade.eed, PID: 11824
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.handmade.eed/com.handmade.eed.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:615)
            at com.handmade.overt.visible.OvertButton.resize(OvertButton.java:61)
            at com.handmade.overt.visible.OvertButton.<init>(OvertButton.java:29)
            at com.handmade.overt.visible.OvertButton.<init>(OvertButton.java:34)
            at com.handmade.eed.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:72)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 09:45:09.872  11824-11824/com.handmade.eed I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11824 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post resize() method..

Comment: posted. Its just `createScaledBitmap`

Comment: have you passded the correct ids??

Comment: @kalyanpvs Yes, that's why I'm confused. If I pass `R.drawable.play_button_pressed_res` (the xml above) it throws a NPE but if I pass `R.drawable.play_button_pressed` (the png) the program will run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of me being dumb but here is the answer for posterity. 
[`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) is not the same as [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)

From the Drawable Resources link above:

> COMPILED RESOURCE DATATYPE:
>   Resource pointer to a BitmapDrawable.

Thus I had to change this:

```
Bitmap pressed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.play_button_pressed_res); //this is the id for the xml referring to the png
```

to either this:

```
Drawable pressed = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.play_button_pressed_res);
```

or this:

```
Bitmap pressed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.play_button_pressed); //this is the id for the png
```

I decided to use `bitmap` because, as I understand, it is faster.